# Missed call notification shown even in auto rejecting or deliberate rejection?

Tags: notifications, missed-calls, samsung-galaxy-note-8, auto-reject

I have a Galaxy Note 8.0 N5100 tablet which is updated to the latest version of Android (4.2.2) using the following official ROM from [SAMMOBILE](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/42360/N5100XXDNK3_N5100OJVDNK1_XSG/).

My problem is even when I deliberately reject someone's calling, there's a notification shown like this:

> [image: missed call notification]

This is really annoying for me because I have put someone in my auto rejection list, but whenever he calls, this notification is shown.

I did factory reset, and now the problem is fixed. But can anyone help me pointing what was wrong? Is it because of the Android update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed. The answer is I had "Any.do" app on my device. I feel like a fool now because instead of thinking about uninstalling an app, I thought that it may be a software bug so I updated my Android version.